# force to forget logins

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

How can I force SSMS to forget the recently used logins?

Of course I use "SQL Server Authentication" with Login/Password fields.

(It get's annoying, as everytime I open SSMS it shows the "Connect to Server"-Dialog, with a login preselected that is not valid anymore.)

Didn't find any option, and no info here.

Thank you.

Comment: I haven't installed SP3 yet, I try this now to see if it maybe resolves the problem (same as using SSMS 2012 would).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you move to SQL Server 2012 Management Studio (and no reason not to, [now that it's free](https://web.archive.org/web/20211206144949/https://sqlblog.org/2012/11/15/sql-server-2012-service-pack-1-is-available-this-time-for-sure) and you can still manage the same set of down-level servers that 2008 R2 lets you manage), you can simply delete old servers right from the connection dialog using the standard Delete key.

- [Deleting Old server names from "Connect to Server" dialog in SSMS](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506174318/http://web.archive.org/web/20150317094913/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/managingsql/archive/2011/07/13/deleting-old-server-names-from-quot-connect-to-server-quot-dialog-in-ssms.aspx)

Comment: It would have been nice if they had implemented the same delete logic for the login list, too. (Edit: Whoops. Accidentally tested on the wrong box.)

Comment: What you mean by free Aaron? I am a bit reluctant to istall the express edition, I don't want to have too many installs. Since when is the full version free?

Comment: Well from the SQL Server Express Download page http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062 the Management Studio is a separate download, so I guess that's what you mean. I'm currently installing it, thank you for the hint!

Comment: @SwissCoder no, did you read my blog post? I think you'll need the SP1 version from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35579

Comment: I read your blogpost, but didn't realize ur link for Express SP1 would point to the full installer. Unfortunately Windows Update seems to be unaware of the SP1, so I have to go for a full download/install again.. (300MB more than the pre SP1 Version, I wonder what they packed in there additionally!)

Comment: good that you mention the build number, as once again the information would not be visible anywhere else that SP1 is installed.

Answer (score 2):

Try to delete the following file and open the SSMS and see.

> C:\Users\gowdhdhan\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\Tools\Shell\SqlStudio.bin

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you Gowdhaman, but I think I will not simply delete all this file, as I see there are many other settings stored in this file as well (for example: Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UserSettings.QueryExecutionSettings). Actually I found the user in there and tried to remove it from that configuration, but when I reopen SSMS it will add the user again to this file...

Comment: Did you deleted alone SqlStudio.bin file. that resolved my problem.

Comment: Hello Gowdhaman, I can deelete only this file, but then I loose other information. I want to explicitly only loose the information for the logins, or better for 1 specific login only.

Comment: I dont think we can do that, because SqlStudio.bin file is the binary file and its very dangerous to edit in binaries.